# To include double quotes within a string

Tags: shell, quoting

My command is

```
X=`ssh ${OS_USER}@${OS_HOST} ". ~/.kshrc ;
   ulimit -c unlimited ;
   cd ${OS_PATH}/NEW_BL1_RC_RATE/bin/conf;
   echo "export RC_DB_INSTANCE=$7" >> RC_CONV_SET_VARS"`
```

`$7` should be presented in double quotes. How it can be done?

Comment: Do you want the file to end up containing `export RC_DB_INSTANCE="$7"`, or `export RC_DB_INSTANCE="foo"` where `foo` is the 7th argument to the script that you're running locally?

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple levels of nested double-quotes.  that gets very tricky, very ugly, and very difficult to read and modify.  e.g. `

```
ssh ${OS_USER}@${OS_HOST} \
    ". ~/.kshrc; ... ;
     echo \"export RC_DB_INSTANCE=\\\"\\\$7\\\"\" >> RC_CONV_SET_VARS".
```

(NOTE: i tested that multi-quoted `echo` with `bash -c` on my system, and it worked with that but I'm not even 100% sure that it will work in `ssh`.  Multiple levels of quotes and backslashes are a PITA and should be avoided)

and then it gets even more complicated if RC_CONV_SET_VARS is not a literal filename but a variable name....further complicated depending on whether RC_CONV_SET_VARS is local to your system or to the remote system.

It's much easier to write a simple throwaway script, `scp` it to the remote host, and then run it there with `ssh`.

For example:

Save the following as `myscript.ksh`:

```
#! /usr/bin/ksh
. ~/.kshrc
ulimit -c unlimited
cd ${OS_PATH}/NEW_BL1_RC_RATE/bin/conf
echo 'export RC_DB_INSTANCE="$7"' >> "$RC_CONV_SET_VARS"
```

Then `scp` it to remote host and run it:

```
scp myscript.ksh "${OS_USER}@${OS_HOST}:/tmp/"
ssh "${OS_USER}@${OS_HOST}" 'ksh /tmp/myscript.ksh'
```

There are still quoting issues to be resolved, but they're pretty much the same as you'd have with quoting when writing a script you intend to run on the local system.  Not ugly, complicated, and confusing multiple levels of backslash-escaping and quotes.

If this seems impractical because you'd have to type the password multiple times, then don't  do that - set up key-based authentication and **don't use password-based authentication with ssh**.

BTW, you can pass whatever args you need on the `ksh myscript.sh` command line.

```
ssh "${OS_USER}@${OS_HOST}" 'ksh /tmp/myscript.ksh arg1 arg2 arg3'
```

or, if you need to pass the 7th arg of the **local** script to the remote script:

```
ssh "${OS_USER}@${OS_HOST}" "ksh /tmp/myscript.ksh \"$7\""
```

and change the last line of `myscript.ksh` above to something like:

```
echo "export RC_DB_INSTANCE=\"$1\"" >> "$RC_CONV_SET_VARS"
```

Answer (score -1):

You will have to "escape" the quotes:

```
echo "export RC_DB_INSTANCE=\"$7\""
```

will do the trick...

Comment: Tried it in the first place - it doesn't work.

Comment: Please clarify: The term "export .... =$7" shall be written to the file RC_CONV_SET_VARS on the remote host? Or do you try to intend something different?

Comment: Correct - shall be written to the file RC_CONV_SET_VARS on the remote host

Comment: No, that sends `"` to the remote shell, which parses it, so that the file ends up containing `export RC_DB_INSTANCE=foo` if `$7` is `foo`.